# Using Request to Response.Write an error message

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wish to use output an error message to the page (using `Response.Write`) depending on an optional paramter of `Request`.

```
  string errorMessage = "";

  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage))
  {
      errorMessage = Request["msg"].Trim();
  }

  switch (errorMessage)
  {
      case "error":
          Response.Write(@"We apologise for the delay, this is due to a site issue. We expect this to be resolved shortly. Please <a href=""/"">try again</a> in a few minutes.");
          break;
      case "288":
          Response.Write("We will be back soon!");
          break;
      default:
          Response.Write("We are working on it...");
          break;
  }
```

I don't get an exception, and the default switch works, it prints: "We are working on it..." to the page, but it doesn't change depending on the parameter "msg" passed to the request.

Comment: If you apply a debugger to this part of your code I am sure you'll figure out what the issue is

Comment: Your if-statement will always return `false` so you never read from the Request

Comment: If I takeaway the If statement, it works, providing I've passed a URL. How could I get it to jump to default, if nothing is passed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if`-statement will always return `false` so you never read from the `Request`.

If you want to check whether a parameter named "key" was passed, you can check `Request["msg"]` instead of `errorMessage`, because [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.item(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> If the specified key is not found, then null is returned.

```
string errorMessage = "";

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["msg"])) // 
{
    errorMessage = Request["msg"].Trim();
}

switch (errorMessage)
{
  /*...*/
}
```

Comment: Very helpful @stephan. Thank you for helping.